# Ip Address Of Machine From Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am using an emulator and a local server to run a certain app.
Because it is a school project I need to show the app to a tester and then the app would be checked by a different tester without me showing it.
As the app needs to call the local server it needs to know the ip of the machine running the server.
How can the emulator gain the ip of the machine running it?
Tried using LocalHost and 127.0.0.1 instead if the ip address 10.0.0.10 that I had but it didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The localhost refers to the device on which the code is running, in this case, the emulator.

If you want to refer to the computer which is running the Android simulator, use the IP address 10.0.2.2 instead. You can read more from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline.html#networkaddresses).